# react-native keyboard with 'hide keyboard' button?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, keyboard

For iOS/Android i think there's a way to have a keyboard where instead of the 'Return' button there's a "Hide keyboard" button. But I can't see this as a type of option. I want to use a single line text input area, but let the user easily and obviously click to dismiss the keyboard.

ideally this would be cross platform too, but android phones usually have a more obvious way to hide the keyboard in the UX.

Is there a way to choose a type of keyboard that by default has the "Return" replaced with "Close"? On an iPad this seems to happen automatically.

Or to change the return button to "Done"?

docs:

- https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/
- https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard
- input accessory view https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory

Answer (score 0):

Not possible on Android.  They keyboard is a separate app that gets to decide what buttons it shows.  There's a limited set of hints you can give it, but it gets final say and can ignore those hints.  The built in options are DONE, GO, NEXT, PREVIOUS, SEARCH, and SEND.  And of course many keyboards use it for an emoticon key.  But hide isn't a thing that's built in, a keyboard would need to choose to use the enter key for that.  Which doesn't make a lot of sense on Android, because the back button hides it without using up keyboard screen area.